# RealVNC on Mac OS accessing Linux box – how to switch between Spaces?

Tags: macos, realvnc, xfce4

I'm running Debian 8 with XFCE. Most of the time I'm accessing this box via VNC from my Mac (with El Capitan) using the RealVNC client. The client is set to full screen, so that it gets its own space in MacOS. Everything works fine including key mappings, beside one annoyance.

I cannot switch between MacOS Spaces once I'm in the RealVNC Space. I'm not using the Magic Mouse that would give me a double-finger swipe, so I have to use CTRL-RIGHT and CTRL-LEFT to switch between Spaces in MacOS. But CTRL-LEFT/RIGHT aren't passed through to MacOS, because something in XFCE seems to catch that key combination. I'm already checked xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts, there is no such combination.

Comment: Does F3 [or Fn/F3] work to get the Mission Control overview? If it does, that's probably your easiest workaround. All remote software seems to suffer from similar key-steals, including Apple's own Remote Desktop. Solution is to set your own key commands differently to the standard, so you don't get 'caught'.

Comment: Unfortunately F3 doesn't work either.

Comment: you have to release keyboard control from vnc first, ctrl-opt I think, but vnc tells you the key sequence to unlock when you connect, since you can configure the key sequence.